# Construct strings in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, path, helper

I have a model called `Book` and another one called `Magazine`.

They share the same index view, where pictures of the covers are shown.They are also displayed according to their appearance date, so instances of those two models are mixed in the view...

Each cover has a clickable tite, and leads the user to a description page for this particular book or magazine...

Now in my view,i want to be able to do something like :

```
<%= link_to document.title, "#{document.class.name.underscore}"_path(document) %>
```

So in the case of book, i want this line to be replaced by the path from `book_path(document)` when document is a book,and by the path generated by `magazine_path(document)` when the document is a magazine.

À la bash script syntax...

How would i realize this.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= link_to document.title, polymorphic_path(document) %>
```

Polymorphic path, when executed with a model, checks the class of passed model, brings it do underscored notation and executes `model_name_path`. Seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what it was intended for!  See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) for more.

Comment: Very elegant solution ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this with **eval**.

```
<%= link_to "Title", eval("#{document.class.name.underscore}_path(document)") %>
```

There is also **send**, which is cleaner, but also metaprogramming:

```
<%= link_to "Title", send("#{document.class.name.underscore}_path", document) %>
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, but there are usually better ways than using `eval`.

Comment: I understand. But I really think that's what @user3442206 is asking for.

Comment: I didn't down vote neither ! And it worked ! Thanks !